# Не отправляется письмо через sendmail в Homestead

Tags: php, linux, laravel, email, vagrant

Дано: Laravel, Vagrant, Homestead.

Пытаюсь отправить хоть какое-то письмо через драйвер sendmail или нативными методами php. П.С. Через драйвер smtp все хорошо.

Судя по логам - вроде письма отправляются, 250 код. Но в конечной точке их нет. Ни в спаме, ни где. Пробовал и реальную почту, и тестовую.

```
        $to= 'test-tmy1o@mail-tester.com';
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = 'hello';
        $headers = array(
            'From' => 'pavel@yandex.ru',
            'Reply-To' => 'test-tmy1o@mail-tester.com',
            'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
        );

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        mail($to, $subject, $message);

        Mail::to('test-ozll8@mail-tester.com')->send(new OrderShipped());
```

Логи /var/log/mail.log

```
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/pickup[6769]: 2DEE143EDF: uid=1000 from=<vagrant>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/cleanup[7378]: 2DEE143EDF: message-id=<20190828082005.2DEE143EDF@vagrant.vm>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 2DEE143EDF: from=<vagrant@homestead>, size=381, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/pickup[6769]: 3002143EE0: uid=1000 from=<vagrant>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/cleanup[7378]: 3002143EE0: message-id=<20190828082005.3002143EE0@vagrant.vm>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 3002143EE0: from=<vagrant@homestead>, size=303, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/smtp[7384]: 2DEE143EDF: to=<test-tmy1o@mail-tester.com>, relay=localhost[::1]:1025, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as odPr2R1x8Jyi13eimLH30McNvCU5PjiZPCv9ufvhWK8=@mailhog.example)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 2DEE143EDF: removed
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/smtp[7384]: 3002143EE0: to=<test-tmy1o@mail-tester.com>, relay=localhost[::1]:1025, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.02/0.04/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as GGJwh49pPpmd_6bkz5-ws1Nu0oqaPZP0ctYMlywqZ1w=@mailhog.example)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 3002143EE0: removed
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/pickup[6769]: 4F1FB43EE1: uid=1000 from=<example@example.com>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/cleanup[7378]: 4F1FB43EE1: message-id=<c57184d8c679104fad3442006cff67d6@laravel>
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 4F1FB43EE1: from=<example@example.com>, size=482, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/smtp[7385]: 4F1FB43EE1: to=<test-ozll8@mail-tester.com>, relay=localhost[127.0.0.1]:1025, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as RrfRudQ6FUO1gf-gmvYkVUjLPv5wIW4NfAz4jHIJsbU=@mailhog.example)
Aug 28 08:20:05 homestead postfix/qmgr[2056]: 4F1FB43EE1: removed
```

П.С.

Кажется письма перехватываются MailHog. Как его отключить временно?

Answer (score 1):

Одна из возможных причин - вы указываете фейковый From, работая с sendmail. Ваш From должен соответствовать вашей доменной почте, с которого вы пытаетесь отправить сообщение. В данном коде я вижу From с доменным именем yandex.ru. Попробуйте указать актуальное доменное имя почты.

Comment: Пробовал. Причина не в этом. Да и поле from не обязательно должно соответствовать почте откуда идет письмо. 
Причина в Mailhog. Как его отключить не понятно.